# 7zip "command line error too short switch -o"

Tags: boot, command-line, 20.04, partitioning, 7zip

I am trying to run

```
~$ 7z x '-ir!install.wim' "$Win10_22H2_BrazilianPortuguese_x64" -o"$TEMP"
```

and 7zip gives me

```
Command Line Error:
Too short switch:
-o
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have searched a lot but I didn't find anything...

I am trying to use 7zip as a step in an attempt to split "install.wim" into smaller parts, so that I can make a bootable pendrive to install Windows 10.

Comment: What is the value of `$TEMP`? I guess the variable is not set.

Comment: Check: `$ env | grep TEMP`

Comment: Or simply `echo $TEMP`.

Comment: Now I tried these two commands and nothing happened, also tried running < 7z x '-ir!install.wim' "$Win10_22H2_BrazilianPortuguese_x64" -o"$Documentos" > instead of $TEMP only to get the same error... the objective is to move the smaller parts of <install.wim> to a temporary location, I'm following a tutorial i found,

Comment: @luana-tho, make sure there's no space between -o and $TEMP -- $TEMP will be having some space prepended,